# Get part of whole page with file_get_html and PHP Simple HTML DOM.?

Tags: php, dom

here is my code :

```
<?php

 include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.bbc.com');

    $html = strstr($html, '<span class="module__title__link tag tag--feature">Rio 2016</span>');
    $html = strstr($html, '<span class="module__title__link tag tag--feature">Editor’s Picks</span>', true);
    $html = substr($html, 0, -1);

foreach($html->find('div.media__content') as $article) {

  echo $article; } 

?>
```

i use `strstr` to return part of that page, and when i `echo $html;` everything is ok.

but i got : `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object`

What should I do?

UPDATE : explain what i want to do :

> 1 : Parse "bbc.com" as html
>   2 : Trim part of that
>   3 : assign the part to $html
>   4 : Find the sections and assign it to string like :
>   `$item['description'] = $article->find('a', 0)->href;`

Comment: because you converted $html object to string

Comment: remove those *html = strstr()* from code

Comment: but i use `strstr` to return specified part of whole Webpage. if i removing the lines, the script searchs all of webpage.

Comment: check i am posting the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

use str inside foreach loop

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.bbc.com');

        foreach($html->find('div.media__content') as $article) {

         echo strstr($article, 'What You Want To Search');

             } 

        ?>
```

Comment: echo strstr($article, '<span class="module__title__link tag tag--feature">Rio 2016</span>');  
  
it's return null; i think a mistaken from my question,explain what i want to do :  
  
1 : Parse "bbc.com" as html  
2: Trim part of that  
3 : assign the part to $html  
4: Find the sections and assign it to string like :   
  
`$item['description'] = $article->find('a', 0)->href;`

Answer (score -1):

$html is a string not an object, therefore, you can't call a method on it.

Comment: @MehdiBoveiri I don't know, are you using a library to parse html ?

Comment: i use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @MehdiBoveiri As alreay answered above by Vishnu Bhadoriya, your problem comes from using strstr. You should replace it by using the find method, then looping through the results and then finding every div.media__content.